# How do you expose a closure from within a @propertywrapper?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, properties, closures

I am trying to write a property wrapper to bind two variables together. The problem I am having is that when I call the projectedValue property my closure returns nil. I want to be able to assign a value to the closure once the value of the observed item is changed.

This is my property wrapper class.

```
@propertyWrapper
class State<Instance> {

    typealias projectedClosure = (Instance) ->Void


    init(wrappedValue: Instance) {
        self.instance = wrappedValue
    }

     var projectedValue : Binding<Instance>  {
        Binding<Instance>(value: instance)
    }

    private var instance : Instance {
        didSet{
            projectedValue.value = instance
        }
    }

    var wrappedValue: Instance {
        get{
            return instance
        }
        set{
            instance = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The propertyWrapper projects this class

```
class Binding<Element> {

    var handler : ((Element)->Void)?

    var value :Element {
        didSet{
            guard let handlerClosure = handler else {
                print("Handler is null")
                return
            }
            handlerClosure(value)
        }
    }

    init(value:Element) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Finally, I am implementing this in a playground before porting it over into my actual project. This is how I am executing the methods.

```
class TestPropertyWrapperObserver {

    @State var name : String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var test = TestPropertyWrapperObserver(name: "Thomas")

var ryan = "ryan"

test.$name.handler = { item in
    ryan = item
    print(item)
}

test.name = "bradly"
test.name = "fake"

print(ryan)
```

My print log is:

```
Handler is null
Handler is null
ryan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you made `projectedValue` a computed property, so every time you do this:

```
projectedValue.value = instance
```

a *new* `Binding` instance is created.

Instead, you should make `projectedValue` a stored property, and initialise it in `init`, *once*:

```
init(wrappedValue: Instance) {
    self.instance = wrappedValue
    projectedValue = Binding<Instance>(value: instance)
}

let projectedValue : Binding<Instance>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb! Thank you man!!! I've been staring at the screen for hours.